# "Method not found" Exception while upgrading dwr from 2.0 to 3.0

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dwr

I am facing below issue while upgrading dwr from 2.0 to 3.0. The underlying application is spring mvc based and I have also added corresponding `spring-dwr` xsd's after the upgrade. I am facing this issue while call is being passed to delegate js to `delegate` service.

Any help to mitigate this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance !

```
2015-09-24 13:45:14,511 WARN [org.directwebremoting.extend.Call] - <No methods called 'findxxxxxxxx' in BeanCreator for com.abc.xyz.delegators.XXXXServiceDelegate are applicable for the passed parameters.>
2015-09-24 13:45:14,511 DEBUG [org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallHandler] - <Marshalling exception>
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Method not found. See logs for details
    at org.directwebremoting.extend.Call.findMethod(Call.java:247)
    at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallHandler.marshallInbound(BaseCallHandler.java:205)
    at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallHandler.handle(BaseCallHandler.java:108)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your 'dwr-controller' is given with 'debug=true' option, check the dwr debug page by adding "/dwr/(welcome page-defaultly index.html)".. list of beans will be shown,exploring your bean might help.